# Winforms taskbar hide/overlay

Tags: c#, winforms, hide, overlay, taskbar

I m trying to solve problem in my fullscreen application. When I start the app it is fullscreen. That is handled by this code

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        //this.TopMost = true;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    }


    private void Hlavni_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        //this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    }
```

When opening another fullscreen Form, everything works fine. Taskbar is cover with and doesn't show up. The problem occurs when I want to open 3rd form. This one is not meant to be fullscreen and serves for purpose similar to MessageBox.
While is this form open, taskbar is also visible untill the form is closed again. I tried somehow to update/change bounds of that form but it only led to making this form fullscreen.

Any idea how to show desired form and keep taskbar hidden?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
Adding the code for 3rd form

```
 public RadForm3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.TopMost = true;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }

    private void RadForm3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        this.CenterToScreen();  
        ...
    }
```

Comment: pls, publish your code.

Comment: Could you add the code where you instantiate the 3rd window and show it please?

Comment: When you display the "message", set the main fullscreen form as the owner.  Either `xxx.Show(this);` or `xxx.ShowDialog(this);`.

Comment: @Idle_Mind  It was a little bit tricky for me because I was opening that form from another thread, but it solved my problem. Thank you!